# Ubuntu grub menu - detect partitions

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, grub

I installed Ubuntu to spare raw partitions using VirtualBox, and have managed to get it to boot up and get it fully working in VirtualBox.

Now I want to be able to boot it natively too. My current/host OS is Ubuntu. My host Grub menu can't seem to detect the new Ubuntu install on the other partitions so I can't select the new Ubuntu to boot natively. Otherwise I can boot into my current/host OS fine.

Is there a way where I can get Grub to auto detect or reconfigure itself to detect the new Ubuntu OS on the other partitions?

Thanks

Comment: Have you run `sudo update-grub`?

Comment: Just saw your comment after I found the solution, yes that was the command that fixed it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it. Had to do

`sudo update-grub`